# Show div if multiple radio buttons checked

Tags: jquery, hide

So I'm trying to make a div id only appear only if multiple radio buttons are checked with Jquery, I found a solution that works if ONE button is checked, but I cannot find a solution that checks for multiple buttons being checked at once.

It's for a multiple choice quiz so let's say I have 4 questions with 3 answers I need it to check if the right answers are checked in all questions.

This is what I have to check if one radio button is checked which is currently working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="q1a1"){
            $("#div").show();
        }
        else{
            $("#div").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

q1a1 being the first answer in the first question.

my idea was to replace

```
if($(this).attr("value")=="q1a1")
```

with

```
if($('input[name="q1"]').attr("value")=="q1a1")
```

and have the IF statement check all 4 radio button names for their value with && but I can't seem to make it work. Am I replacing $(this) wrong or can you simply not do what I'm attempting to?

EDIT: live version of the code since JSfiddle is down atm: http://vendila.dk/formtest/

Comment: Why are you checking the value, wouldn't it be easier to just get the one that is checked ?

Comment: And post your complete code please.

Comment: If you're actually checking for radio buttons, I don't think that's possible. Radio buttons are meant for a single choice. If you're using checkboxes, you may want to update your question.

Comment: JSfiddle is down atm, will upload full code when it is up.

Comment: Everyone can view your script, so answers will not be secret. Consider using a server side check if this matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for correct answers using the `:checked` selector.

```
if($('input[value=q1a1]:checked, input[value=q2a2]:checked, input[value=q3a3]:checked').length == 3){
  $("#div").show();
}else{
  $("#div").hide();
}
```

Comment: See the updated answer, I had a typo. Remove the interior quotes in the selector.

Comment: Fantastic. Code runs on live final version, thanx for your time.